# Using Gtk.TreeDragSource.drag_data_get()

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

I have a simple Gtk.TreeView with a Gtk.ListStore with four columns as the model. I want to be able to drag and drop rows within the TreeView and track row insertions, changes and deletions as they happen so I can implement undo/redo to drag and drop operations. I'm using PyGObject 3 and Python 3.2.

I thought that using methods under the Gtk.TreeDragSource and Gtk.TreeDragDest interfaces would suit my needs perfectly, with Gtk.TreeDragSource.drag_data_get() in my drag_data_get handler and Gtk.TreeDragDest.drag_data_received() or Gtk.tree_get_row_drag_data() in my drag_data_received handler. Basically, what I've tried looks something like this:

```
def drag_data_get(self, tv, context, selection, target_id, time):
    treeselection = tv.get_selection()
    model, my_iter = treeselection.get_selected()
    path = model.get_path(my_iter)
    result = Gtk.TreeDragSource.drag_data_get(path, selection)

def drag_data_received(self, tv, context, x, y, selection,  info, time):
    result, model, row = Gtk.tree_get_row_drag_data(selection)
    my_iter = model.get_iter(row)
    data = [model.get_value(my_iter, i) for i in range(model.get_n_columns())]
    drop_info = tv.get_dest_row_at_pos(x, y)
    if drop_info:
        path, position = drop_info
        my_iter = model.get_iter(path)
        if (position == Gtk.TreeViewDropPosition.BEFORE
            or position == Gtk.TreeViewDropPosition.INTO_OR_BEFORE):
            model.insert_before(my_iter, [data])
        else:
            model.insert_after(my_iter, [data])
    else:
        model.append([data])    
    if context.get_actions() == Gdk.DragAction.MOVE|Gdk.DragAction.DEFAULT:
        context.finish(True, True, time)
    return
```

This fails spectacularly - when Python hits the call to Gtk.TreeDragSource.drag_data_get(), Python crashes and my program window swiftly disappears. I don't even get to the drag_data_received handler. Can anyone point me to some example code showing how these methods using the TreeDragSource and TreeDragDest interfaces work? Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You seem to have some edit errors.  Both methods are named the same, first uses tv but doesn't define it, for ex.  Also, are you sure my_iter is always valid? Might try checking before getting path.

Comment: @ergosys That's what posting when tired and frustrated will cause: errant cutting and pasting. I've now fixed the signature of my drag_data_get() method. I have checked to see if the iter and path I use in drag_data_get() are valid before calling Gtk.TreeDragSource.drag_data_get(), and they are, but Python still tosses its cookies every time.

Comment: My DnD-foo is pretty poor, and python worse, but I think calling drag_data_get() in that handler is incorrect.  I believe you are expected to set data in the `selection` object there.  If there's no python example, look for a gtk+ tutorial-- the functions should be similar, and the concepts exactly the same.

Comment: Maybe I just read the API docs on drag_data__get() wrong, but I thought that method was intended to set the selection object to hold a representation of a row in a TreeDragSource such as the ListStore I'm using in my project. I've checked all the tutorials I can find and none talk about how to do DND of multi-column rows in a Gtk.TreeModel (more precisely, how to set the selection object with data representing a multi-column TreeModel row). I had hoped that Gtk.TreeDragSource.drag_data_get() was the solution, but as noted, I've had no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it not work to use `Gtk.tree_set_row_drag_data(selection, model, path)` instead of `result = Gtk.TreeDragSource.drag_data_get(path, selection)`

since your using `Gtk.tree_get_row_drag_data(selection)` anyway?

Comment: yes, that does work; thanks for the suggestion! Strangely enough, although Gtk.TreeDragSource.drag_data_get() crashes Python every time, Gtk.TreeDragDest.drag_data_received() works as expected (once it has a selection object with TreeView row data in it, anyway).  Now if I can just get DND to work without using TreeView.set_reorderable(True) so I can have complete control over when, where and how to insert the row I'm moving back into the TreeView!